# How to catch NegativeArraySizeException?

Tags: java

How to catch `NegativeArraySizeException` in the given set of arrays.Here I want to display the largest number in given arrays ,but it is showing `NegativeArraySizeException`.

Example:

```
12, -23, 34 

TreeSet ts=new TreeSet(); 
public void abc() { 
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); 
    int s1=0; 
    System.out.println("enter number of elemtns "); 
    s1=sc.nextInt(); 
    int i[]=new int[s1]; 

    for(int i2=0; i2<=i.length; i2++) { 
        int s2=sc.nextInt(); 
        if(s2<0) 
            throw new NegativeArraySizeException(); 
        int i1[]=new int[s2]; 
        System.out.println("first,,,,"+s2); 
        ts.add(s2); 
        System.out.println("higest....."+ts.last()); 
    } 
}

public static void main(String[] args) { 
   StringAbc s=new StringAbc(); s.abc(); 
}
```

Comment: `catch(NegativeArraySizeException e)` :D

Comment: Show your code first.

Comment: just use `try-catch`!!!

Comment: What have you done so far?What have you tried? It seems to me that you are just asking for done stuff

Comment: @  Maroun Maroun  have treid but no use.

Comment: edit your question and paste the code in there

Comment: A tip: give your variables meaningful names. `s1`, `i`, `i2`, `s2`, and `i1` convey *zero* meaning, and that makes it hard for you to reason about your code. It makes little sense, for instance, to create an `int[]` of the given size for each number in the input, but due to the obfuscating variable names it's not easy to see that's what happening. In short, your code is not doing anything close to what you intend, so you'd do well to revisit the solution conceptually before trying to "catch NegativeArraySizeException".

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
int arrSize = -8;
try {
    int[] myArray = new int[arrSize];
} catch (NegativeArraySizeException ex) {
    System.out.println("Can't create array of negative size");
}
```

Output: `Can't create array of negative size`

Answer (score 2):

Surround below code in try-catch block

```
StringAbc s=new StringAbc(); s.abc();
```

like

```
try 
{
   StringAbc s=new StringAbc(); s.abc(); 
}
catch (NegativeArraySizeException ex) 
{
   System.out.println( ex.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is you want to implement this

```
public void abc() {
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  int s1=0;
  System.out.println("enter number of elemtns ");

  //Read the size of array from user and check if it is not negative

  s1=sc.nextInt();
  if(s1<0) throw  new NegativeArraySizeException("Array size cannot be negative.");
  int i[]=new int[s1];
  int s2 = 0;
  for(int i2=0;i2<i.length;i2++) {
    System.out.println("Enter element");
    s2=sc.nextInt();

  //get input from user and dont allow negtive numbers in the array

    if(s2<0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative numbers not allowed");
    ts.add(s2);
  }
  System.out.println("first,,,,"+s2);
  System.out.println("higest....."+ts.last());
 }
```

Comment: @Sharma  it is not taking negatives

Comment: thats what is the expected feature right array cannot be created with negative size so you need to handle it.